# PgAdmin4: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR: Connection to the server has been lost

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am writing an email sending function, but an error occurs when creating the function, what should I do?

INTERNAL SERVER ERROR: Connection to the server has been lost

```
import smtplib
sender = _from
receivers = receiver
message = ("From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n %s"
 % (_from,receiver,subject,send_message))

try:

  smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(smtp,port)
  smtpObj.starttls()
  smtpObj.login(_from, _password)
  smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers,message)
  print ('Successfully sent email')
except SMTPException:
  print ('Error: unable to send email')

return message
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jI8B.png)

Comment: Did you check the connection is still ongoing?

Comment: its my local server. Ye, connection present

Comment: You have tagged PostgreSQL tags but you're showing what appears to be Python code for sending an email. What does the code have to do with PostgreSQL?

Comment: In any case, "internal server error" doesn't tell us anything useful. What do your logs say?